# Add a switch for a pool light

Tags: gfci, pool

We just bought a house that needed some upgrades and one of the first ones up was the electrical panel.  Hired an electrical company to come out and upgrade it to a 200amp box.  Work went fine and everything passed inspection but they didn't wire in a switch to control the pool light  Previous owner had cut the wires to the light switch so all that is left is the junction box (wires from light and leading out to missing switch are connected) by the pool and a pipe that contains the cut wires.

When I asked about adding the switch for the pool light I was told it would be a couple hundred dollars since the work order only listed providing GFCI protection for pool light.  So my question is can I add a second switch by using the switch that already exists for my pool pump?  They also installed an exterior outlet so I'm not sure if I can tap into that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the switch for the light and the pool pump, they will always be on simultaneously.  What you can do is splice in a new line and add another switch to the same box as the pump switch.  But it will not have GFCI protection unless your entire pool circuit is GFCI protected at the source.

Comment: To the right of the pump switch is an outlet and I used a plugin GFCI tester this morning and it came back with the two lights that say correct wiring.  If I tap into that, I should be ok right?

Comment: If you use the two load terminals on the GFCI outlet to protect the switch and light, then yes, you will have the GFCI protection.  However, if you connect the switch to the hot *before* the outlet by using a wire nut, you will not get GFCI protection of the light.

Comment: As long as your circuit can support the added load and your pump doesn't required a dedicated circuit, it should be fine to tap into that receptacle.

Comment: You would want GFCI protection on a pool light.  Electrical drowning sucks.  An alternative is to refit 12V LED lighting for the pool light(s), hard to get shocked from 12V.